# Type mismatch with List.map2

Tags: f#

Consider the following

```
let l1 = [1..10]
let l2 = [11..20]
let avg = fun x y-> (x+y)/2.
let c = (l1, l2) ||> List.map2 avg
```

which gives the error

> Type mismatch. Expecting a     int -> int -> 'a     but given a
>   int -> int -> float     The type 'float' does not match the type 'int'

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# does not have automatic conversion from `int` to `float`. `(x+y)` is an `int` value and `2.` is a `float` value. Convert the numerator explicitly:

```
let avg = fun x y -> float (x+y) / 2.
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me.

```
let l1 = [1..10]
let l2 = [11..20]
let avg = fun x y-> float(x+y) / 2.
let c = (l1, l2) ||> List.map2 avg
```